# How can I define which db to pull from via post

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$value = $_POST['directions'];
$value2 = $_POST['inventory'];
$value3 = $_POST['item'];
$value4 = $_POST['vendor'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO a1 (directions,inventory,item,vendor) VALUE ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4')";
```

Right now I'm having a mysql db get updated via what I type in a textbook from a separate page. However where it says "INSERT INTO a1" id like to make "a1" be a variable like "$table" I define from  the same page I type all the other values in

Comment: So make `a1` a variable and not static text (you will probably need to make columns variables too, or a CSV dependent on table). This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: when I make it a variable it waits for me to post it with the others? Im sorry how do I make it a variable without it being posted into the db/ thanks

Comment: `$a1 = $_POST['tablename'];` then `$sql = "INSERT INTO $a1`. Terribly insecure. You should make a static listing of table names and check first that it matches. Your other values should be parameterized.

Comment: As a general rule, I personally avoid dynamic sql. I would either do as chris85 suggested and have some sort of case statement with separate sql strings, or write a stored procedure that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The question need to be more clear, but from my understanding, you can use something like this code :

```
// should be defined like this inside each page.    
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tablename']); 

$params = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if($key!='tablename'){ 
        $params[]= "$key='".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'"; 
    }
}

if(count($params) > 0) {
   $params = implode(",",$params);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET $params";
} else {
   die "Error submitting the data!";
}
```